# Is there a Bell inequality for $2\times 2$ and $1\times1\times1\times1$ configuration?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, observers, correlation-functions, bells-inequality

Bell inequality is violated in entangle experiments is a known phenomenon. The standard experiment is conducted with two parties and is explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem#Bell_inequalities.

I am looking for a mathematical generalization where four parties are involved where

1. the four parties are independent
2. two parties colluding at either ends

Is there direct mathematical answers to these?

Comment: I don't understand the title. The $2\times 2$ scenario would be the standard CHSH one, no? And how do you understand the "$1\times1\times1\times1$ case?" If there is a single possible outcome how can you have any kind of inequality? Anyway, yes you can definitely consider scenarios with more than two parties. See e.g. https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/aaff2d and references therein

Comment: @gIS It is how you organize the experiment. All four parties independent or two sets of two parties collude. Bell inequality is Alice and Bob. 2x2 is (Alice,Christie) vs (Bob,David) and 1x1x1x1 is all independent.

Comment: where is this notation used? If you made it up, then you should explicitly clarify what you mean in the question (not just in  the comments)

Comment: I introduced it.

Comment: anyway, this sounds like what is generally discussed via "DAG diagrams", which consider various possible causal relations between different parties. I'm not sure which one is the standard reference for these but you should find it in the references of Chaves et al. 2018 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.09894)